# How to get all Users with a specific Role from a Group model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, roles

I have a `Group` that has a many-to-many relationship with `User`. And each User can have multiple roles which I implement with [spatie/larevel-permission](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction)

I am trying to retreive all Users attached to a Group that have a specific role, e.g. `learner`

this is what i have so far:

```
class Group extends Model
{
    // other code

    // 
    public function learners(){
        return $this->users::whereHas('roles', function($q) {
            $q->where('name', 'learner');
        })->get();
    }
    
    // other code

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

And I get the error:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereHas does not exist

I understand that `$this->users` returns a `Collection`, and that's why I get that error message. But I'm not sure how else I could **get the users of a group who have the 'learner' role**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling the relationship method `users()` which returns the Belongs To Many relationship not the dynamic property `users` which returns the result of the query for the relationship (Collection). Also you could make the `learners` method a relationship method itself instead of directly returning the result:

```
public function learners()
{
    return $this->users()
        ->whereHas('roles', fn ($q) => $q->where('name', 'learner'));
}

$group->learners;
```

It all depends what you intend to do with this method.

Comment: I changed my query from `users` to `users()` but i then get the error that it must return a relationship instance. I remove the `->get()` and it works! Could I ask you to please explain why and how this worked and why removing `get()` fixed it. Moreover, how would I go about making learners method a relationship? Thank you very much